# Issue in sales order email template in magento2

Tags: magento2, email, sales

I have a custom payment method. For that, if I sent order confirmation email from back-end, means specific information like Credit card number, Auth code, etc. These parameters are coming when the email is sent from back-end but while placing that order in front end using the same credit card, means those information is not coming in email but if I sent from back-end means, it's working fine. Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: The email PHTML files might be different or the email templates might be different. Compare both of them. Check whether the same email template is getting triggered when u place order in both the times!!!

Comment: Both are same email templates only

Comment: Yes. There is only one email template file for sending order confirmation email. Can you share the screenshot showing difference between the emails?

Comment: Actually i have added in back-end email template

Comment: How do you send email from backend? By clicking on Send Email link on top?

Comment: No i have added that template in Marketing->Email Templates

Comment: " These parameters are coming when the email is sent from back-end" How do you send an email from backend? Whatever you set the email template in Marketing >> Email templates, the same will be used for sending Order Confirmation email.

Comment: Yes if i manually sent the email from order view from back-end means mail is working and those parameters coming but while placing order not coming. So , i checked the template it's same.